# C: Segmentation fault when initializing pointers withtin structure

Tags: c

I've created a dynamic int array. I have tested it and it works fine. Now what I want to do is create a structure that uses two pointers to dynamic int arrays.

The DualBuffer definition is done like so:

```
typedef struct {
   DynamicIntArray *active;
   DynamicIntArray *fixed;
} DualBuffer;
```

DynamicIntArray is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int *data;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int used;
    unsigned int sizeIncrease;
} DynamicIntArray;
```

To initialize a DualBuffer I call on this function:

```
DualBuffer dbInitialize(unsigned int starting_size, unsigned int size_increse){
    DualBuffer db;
    diaInitializeArray(db.active,starting_size,size_increse);
    diaInitializeArray(db.fixed, starting_size,size_increse); 
    return db;
}
```

Which calls on the DynamicIntArray intialization function:

```
void diaInitializeArray(DynamicIntArray *a, unsigned int startingSize, unsigned int size_increase){
   a->data = (int *) malloc(startingSize * sizeof(int));
   a->used = 0;
   a->size = startingSize;
   if (size_increase == 0) size_increase = 10;
   a->sizeIncrease = size_increase;
}
```

The only line in my main is this:

```
DualBuffer db = dbInitialize(5,5);
```

However this, generates a segmentation fault. And I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You did not allocated space for `active` and `fixed` so when you pass it to `diaInitializeArray` and accessing as `a->data` you are in trouble Sir.

Comment: In `dbInitialize`, the `db` variable, including its members `active` and `fixed` are uninitialized. You are passing the uninitialized pointer values from `db.active` and `db.fixed` to the `diaInitializeArray` function, and that is dereferencing the uninitialized pointer values, leading to _undefined behavior_ that is manifesting as a segmentation fault in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not allocated space for `active` and `fixed`. You should do something like this in `dbInitialize`:

```
DualBuffer dbInitialize(unsigned int starting_size, unsigned int size_increse){
    DualBuffer db;
    db.active = malloc(sizeof(DynamicIntArray));
    db.fixed = malloc(sizeof(DynamicIntArray));
    diaInitializeArray(db.active,starting_size,size_increse);
    diaInitializeArray(db.fixed, starting_size,size_increse); 
    return db;
}
```

Comment: I had just added this code as I had not idea how to initialize pointers in C (I'm new and used to C++ and new does nto exist here) and It had worked!! Thanks for confirming it though!!!

Comment: @aarelovich You are welcome. And note that if you allocated memory like this then you should free it also with `free()` function at some point.

Comment: Ok. I'll addd that to the dbFree function I've made